# Deploy a ASP-project and write the date in a view

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I want to write the current date in a view or text file when I start the deploy process. 
I want to reach :  the deploy-date is visible in a website.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the deployment date by reading the last modified date of the assembly.   This will tell you the date the website was built and deployed. Be careful to only read the last modified date once (for performance reasons).

```
public static class ApplicationSettings
{
    public static DateTime BuildDate { get; private set; }
    static ApplicationSettings()
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(assembly.Location);
        BuildDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
    }
}
```

Then in your view you could do:

```
Build Date: @ApplicationSettings.BuildDate.ToShortDateString()
```